# Having a trouble with linked lists (adding and printing)

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm too new on data structures, actually i began yesterday. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int x;
    node *next;
};

void addToList(node *r, int a);
void printList(node *r);
int main()
{
    node *root;
    root = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int a;
        scanf("%d", &a);
        addToList(root, a);
    }

    printList(root);

    return 0;
}

void addToList(node *r, int a)
{
    while (r != NULL)
        r = r -> next;

    r = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    r -> x = a;
    r -> next = NULL;
}

void printList(node *r)
{
    while (r != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", r -> x);
        r = r -> next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

I expect the program gets new 5 elements into the list and then prints them. But end of the program nothing is happening. What is my fault?

Comment: it should be `void addToList(node *r, int a){
    while (r->next != NULL)
        r = r -> next;
    r->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    r->next->x = a;
    r->next->next = NULL;
}`

Comment: sorry but it didn't work.

Comment: It worked after defining a first element. Should I define a first element always? No way for a completly empty list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `addToList()` function. If you want to update the root node of the list you have to define your function like that:

```
void addToList(node **r, int a)
```

Otherwise, you're sending the pointer to `root` and doing whatever you doing inside the function. But it doesn't affect `root`'s value on `main()` and it remains `NULL`.

If you want to change the value of the pointer, you have to send from `main()` the address of the pointer to the function ==> `addToList(&root, a);`.

So now we can update where `root` points to. But it's not enough because you want `root` to **always** point to the beginning of the list ==> you want to update it only in the first call to `addToList()`.

Last problem is to add the new created node as the last node in the list. You can do that by saving a temporary pointer to the last node. See my comments in the code (marked my changes with `<<<`):

```
void addToList(node **root, int a)                   <<<
{
    node *r = *root;                                 <<<
    node *last = NULL;                               <<<

    while (r != NULL) {
        last = r;                                    <<<
        r = r -> next;
    }

    r = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    r -> x = a;
    r -> next = NULL;
    if (last == NULL) {                              <<<
        // this is true only on the first call to
        // addToList, so we update root only once
        *root = r;
    } else {
        // all other times we add the new node to be the last one
        last->next = r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `root = NULL` but your `addtoList` function checks if `root !=NULL`. So the test fails there and nothing gets added.
You should have something like this instead:

```
 void addToList(node *r, int a) {
        struct node *temp;
        temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data = a;
        if (r== NULL) {
            r = temp;
            r->next = NULL;
        }
        else {
            temp->next = r;
            r = temp;
        }
}
```

Comment: But that while loop is checks if we are at the last element.

Comment: The first time it runs, `root  = null ` and the test will fail.

Comment: @SHG what I had initially was the body of the `addToList` function. And in his code he is passing `root` as a param to the function. So it should change where `root` points to.

Comment: @Mekicha it changes only inside the function, but not outside. In `main()` root still points to `NULL` after each iteration, it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the first mistake is that you have not taken the `*root` pointer variable as global, so it will not update the value of the `*root` whenever a new node is inserted. It will keep the value of `*root` as `NULL`.

The below code has comments in it, which will explain the various mistakes done by you very easily.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int x;
    node *next;
};
node *root;     //Declaring the *root as global

void addToList(int a);
void printList();
//removing the *root as parameter from both the functions

int main()
{
    root = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    addToList(a);
    }
    printList();
    return 0;
}

void addToList(int a)
{
    //Declaring a temporary pointer(*temp) to avoid the value loss of the *root pointer
    node *temp=root;

    //Declaring a new node to save the data taken from the user
    node *nn = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    //Assigning the values to the new node(*nn)
    nn->x=a;
    nn->next=NULL;

    //Checking that the root node is NULL or not
    //If root is empty, then new node is assigned to *root
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root=nn;
    }
    //Else, we will first find the last node of the linklist using the *temp pointer
    else
    {
        while (temp->next != NULL)
            temp = temp -> next;

        //Assigning the new node after the last node of the linklist
        temp->next=nn;
    }
}

void printList()
{
    node *r=root;
    while (r != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", r -> x);
        r = r -> next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```